# Inner join sql for each record

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a SQL Server database with 2 tables:

- `Customers` table (cusId, cusName) with 40 records
- `Transactions` table (tranId, cusId, payee) with 228 records.

I am trying to find out how I can return the number of transactions per customer for all of them as shown below.

For example:

```
1. Michael Piers 21
2. John    Lian  66
.
.
.
40. Paul Andrew 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a join on both these tables,  select Customers.cusName,count(Transactions.tranId) and group by Customers.cusId

Something like this, I have not tested the query but it should work:

```
SELECT Customers.cusName,COUNT(Transactions.tranId) AS TransactionsCount FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Transactions
ON Customers.cusId=Transactions.cusId
GROUP BY Customers.cusId;
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!